# Correct way of Initializing a Vector in Verilog

Tags: vector, initialization, verilog

What is the difference in initializing a vector in Verilog these ways?

```vhdl
reg [3:0] vector = 4'b0000;
```

or

```vhdl
reg [3:0] vector = 0;
```

The only advantage I see in the first initialization is setting every bit directly. But in this example setting the vector to zero, is there a difference at all? Is one way better than the other?

**EDIT:**

I expanded the test program of mcleod_ideafix a bit to check some other things:

```vhdl
module tb;
  reg [15:0] v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10;

  initial begin        
    v6 = 1'b0;
    v7 = 1'b1;
    v8 = 2'b1111;
    v9 = 'b1;
    v10 = 6'b11;
    
    $display ("v5(=/)       = %b\nv6(=1'b0)    = %b\nv7(=1'b1)    = %b\nv8(=2'b1111) = %b\nv9(='b1)     = %b\nv10(=6'b11)  = %b", v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10);
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

Which results in:

```
v5(=/)       = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
v6(=1'b0)    = 0000000000000000
v7(=1'b1)    = 0000000000000001
v8(=2'b1111) = 0000000000000011
v9(='b1)     = 0000000000000001
v10(=6'b11)  = 0000000000000011
```

- v5 shows, that a non initialized variable is x, so undefined as expected.
- v6 is set to 1'b0, so only one bit should be set to 0 but all bits are set to 0.
- On the other hand v7 is set to 1'b1 and only the least significant bit is set to 1. On my perspective all non given leading bits will set to zeros whenever a variable is set to a value.
- v8 shows, that the number before the ' limits the size of the given number behind 'b'.
  Setting v8 gives me some warnings:

  test.v:7: warning: extra digits given for sized binary constant.
  test.v:7: warning: Numeric constant truncated to 2 bits.

According to the given warnings, I don't think, this "feature" is intended, so I would always prefer:

```vhdl
reg [3:0] vector = 2'b10
```

- Removing the length of the number (v9) is more save i think, because it is not possible to forget updating the length when changing the value of the number. The only advantage of writing the length in the number would be a cross-check of the length. So If the length is set smaller as the real length of the value, I get a warning. On the other hand, setting the length longer than the real value doesn't give a warning (v10). So the cross-check doesn't seem to be the intention too?

**Back to my starting question**: There is no real difference in setting a vector these ways, isn't it? So I would use the "long" form:

```vhdl
reg [3:0] vector = 'b1011;
```

only to set a reg to a specific value in binary or hex. Setting to a decimal or to zero:

```vhdl
reg [3:0] vector = 0;
```

is shorter, more intuitive and more save, because I can not forget changing the length.

Only aesthetics could lead someone to write 1'b0.

Comment: do *not* initialize vectors this way in rtl code. It is not synthesizable in generic case (excluding some fpga). Other than that there is not much difference between those 2 cases. The first one would be better  if you had not used `2` instead of `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The second one will treat 0 as a 32-bit integer, so it's equivalent to

```
reg [3:0] vector = 32'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;
```

For simulation: as long as vector size is no more than 32 bits, it's fine. You may get warnings about operand being truncated to fit. But if vector is greater than 32 bits, bits starting from 32 will be x in your simulations.

**EDIT: seems like it is not that way, and 0 can be used to initialize any size. See example below**

There is this other notation for which the synthesizer/compiler will expand the operand to fit the L-value:

```
reg [3:0] vector = 'b0;
```

For FPGA synthesis, non-initialized vectors will be initialized to the default configured in your synthesizer/bitstream generation process, which is normally 0.

```
module tb;
  reg [3:0] v1, v2, v3;
  reg [127:0] v4;

  initial begin
    v1 = 0;
    v2 = 4'b0000;
    v3 = 'b0;
    v4 = 0;
    
    $display ("%b %b %b %b", v1, v2, v3, v4);
    $finish;
  end
endmodule

[2020-06-28 09:49:37 EDT] iverilog '-Wall' design.sv testbench.sv  && unbuffer vvp a.out  
0000 0000 0000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I took you testprogram and expanded it by some other values as written in my start question.

Answer (score 1):

A numeric literal with no base or size is treated as a signed, 32-bit value. Verilog allows assignments from any size to any other size, and will implicitly truncate or extend the value silently. This is known as *weakly typed*.

When you write `2'b0000`, you are specifying a 2-bit unsigned binary number, but you wrote out 4 digits. The number will be truncated to 2-bits. But since you are making an assignment to a 4-bit variable, the value hets extended back to 4 bits.

So the end result is the same for each type of initialization.

**EDIT:**

Your edit changed the question topic slightly, but the answer is still the same for the code in your example—the result is the same. But that is not always the case when literals are used within an expression. Size matters.

Comment: Yep, that was not the intended topic, so I corrected it to 4'b0000!

Comment: That changed the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The original Question posted this line of code:

```
reg [3:0] vector = 2'b0000;
```

---

You might get a compile warning in your first statement with some simulators because you used `2` as the size of the numerical literal value.  You probably meant to use `4`:

```
reg [3:0] vector = 4'b0000;
```

Aside from that, you should see that your 2 statements will simulate the same way.